# python function access to main variable

Tags: python

I know this is a stupid question, but it's happening on my side.

```
def func():
    print(name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    name = "halo"
    print(name)

    func()
```

As I know, `func( )` can't see name variable.
But its showing "halo" twice.

I am working in PyCharm.
Any suggestion? Or python originally works in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`func` *can* see the `name` variable. It is a global variable, because the place where you created it is not inside any class or function. All functions can read global variables.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer. May I get some suggestion to search keyword to figure out how things are working in Python?

Comment: @cogito I think you are looking for the word "scope" or "variable scope" here.

Comment: You could also check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do